# Can we write the real part of this expression?

Tags: complex-numbers

Assuming $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $b >0$, is there a way we can simplify the real part of this expression?
$$ i ab \left(e^{-i \sqrt{-a^4 -i a b}}-e^{i \sqrt{-a^4 +i a b}}\right) $$

In case it matters, it was derived using the $(-\infty, 0)$ branch cut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$:

$$\Re\left(iab\left(e^{-i\sqrt{-a^4-iab}}-e^{i\sqrt{-a^4+iab}}\right)\right)=$$
$$\Im\left(ab\left(e^{i\sqrt{-a^4+iab}}-e^{-i\sqrt{-a^4+iab}}\right)\right)=$$ 
$$\Im\left(ab\cdot e^{i\sqrt{-a^4+iab}}\right)-\Im\left(ab\cdot e^{-i\sqrt{-a^4+iab}}\right)=$$
$$-\Im\left(ab\left(e^{-i\sqrt{-a^4-iab}}-e^{i\sqrt{-a^4+iab}}\right)\right)=$$
$$2\Re\left(ab\cdot\sin\left(\sqrt{-a^4+iab}\right)\right)=$$

$$2ab\sin\left(\sqrt[4]{a^8+a^2b^2}\cdot\cos\left(\frac{1}{2}\arg\left(-a^4+iab\right)\right)\right)\cdot\cosh\left(\sqrt[4]{a^8+a^2b^2}\cdot\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}\arg\left(-a^4+iab\right)\right)\right)$$